# Unity SampleTexture2D messed up colors

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, shader-graph

Today when I was following a tutorial to make a simple highlight shader, I found sampleTexture2d messed up the colors inside the image, and to simplify the problem, I deleted all other nodes, you can see the pictures for detail.It's a URP unlit shadergraph.

[image: The shader graph]

[image: original image and the one of shader graph]

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but this might have to do with a quirk in the image editor. Default settings usually save the color value for alpha pixels and if you only use the color values (Base Color drops the fourth alpha channel) you get to see all the old editing "smears". If you have the OG image it would be easy to check.